# Forcing intellij Idea to work with another git repository

Tags: git, intellij-idea

My project looks like this

```
|.git(this is the project's git)
|--App1
|--App2
|--MyApp |.git (this is the git for heroku with dummy commits)
         |--SubFolder1
         |--SubFolder2
```

I have another git repository for heroku deployments.

I work with intellij-idea only with the "MyApp" folder.

Intellij works with ./MyApp/.git repository.

Is there any way to tell intellij idea to work with ./.git repository?

**Aka can i set the git repository path or ignore a given .git repository?**

Comment: I believe you can define specific repository directories in `Settings->Version control`.

Comment: @Vic, not sure it will work as git will use the first uplevel `.git` configuration directory it finds.

Comment: You could add another repository/master as branch to dummy repository and switch branches whenever you need

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to make IntelliJ work with this setup.

Moreover, setting up such a workspace is not straightforward in Git itself, though possible.
If you are inside MyApp, but want to work with the "parent" Git repository, you have to prefix all your commands with `--git-dir` command that lets you specify the location of .git:

```
cd .../project/MyApp
git --git-dir=.../project/.git status
```

To work with a repository IntelliJ invokes Git commads like status, push, etc. And it doesn't support specifying git-dir for them. Maybe it will be implemented in future if you open a feature request in [JetBrains bugtracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com), but not in the nearest future.